# Update timestamp values by subtracting 4 hours from each record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `created_at` timestamp field. I need to update and subtract 4 hours from every record.

This is about **updating the records**, not changing the results of a query.

So `2014-08-20 18:00:00` would become `2014-08-20 14:00:00`.

And `2014-08-21 03:00:00` would become `2014-08-20 23:00:00`.

Comment: That's not duplicate. The other question connected here is just to add/subtract and show them. Here, it is about making the changes to the field itself.

Comment: @SenG indeed. Edited the question and started a vote to reopen the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a simple UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE yourtable SET created_at = created_at - INTERVAL 4 HOUR;
```

This will update all rows accordingly to your needs:

From the documentation to [DATE_ADD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

> Date arithmetic also can be performed using INTERVAL together with the
>   + or - operator:
>
> date + INTERVAL expr unit
>   date - INTERVAL expr unit

Comment: oh hey vmai! :) nice answer.. beat me by a few seconds!

Comment: @JohnRuddell And *Ende Neu* did beat me my some seconds, so I upvoted you both.

Comment: For anyone else looking for the equivalent syntax in postgres: `UPDATE yourtable SET created_at = created_at - INTERVAL '4 HOURS'`

Answer (score 5):

You can use `INTERVAL` to specify the time that needs to be subtracted:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET created_at = created_at - INTERVAL 4 HOUR
```

Answer (score 3):

few ways you can do this.

you can set the date equal to another date that is interval'd 4 hours earlier like so

using adddate()

```
UPDATE table SET created_at = ADDDATE(created_at, INTERVAL -4 HOUR);
```

using date_sub

```
UPDATE table set created_at = DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 4 HOUR);
```

using just interval

```
UPDATE table SET created_at = (created_at - INTERVAL 4 HOUR);
```